# Parallelization loop R "repeat"

Tags: r, loops, parallel-processing, repeat

this is my first post on this forum so if I don't do things correctly, please tell me I'm correcting it!

So here's my problem: at the end of one of my R programs, I do a simple loop using "repeat". This loop will perform a series of calculations for each month of the year 137 times, making a total of 1,646 repetitions. This takes time, about 50 minutes.

```
numero_profil_automatisation = read.csv2("./import_csv/numero_profil_automatisation.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
    n=1
    repeat {
      annee="2020"

      annee_profil="2020"

      mois_de_debut="1"

      mois_de_fin="12"

      operateur=numero_profil_automatisation[n,1]



profil_choisi=numero_profil_automatisation[n,3]
  couplage=numero_profil_automatisation[n,4]

  subvention=numero_profil_automatisation[n,5]

  type=numero_profil_automatisation[n,6]

  seuil=0.05

  graine=4356

  
  resultat=calcul_depense(annee,annee_profil,mois_de_debut,mois_de_fin,operateur,
                          profil_choisi,couplage,subvention,type,graine,seuil)

  
  nom=paste("./resultat_csv/",operateur,an,type,couplage,subvention,
            profil,".csv",sep="_")
  write.csv2(resultat,nom)

  n<-n+1
  if (n == 138) break
}
```

I would like to optimize the code, so I talked to a friend of mine, a computational developer (who doesn't "know" R) who advised me among other things to parallelize the calculations. My new work computer has 4 cores (R detects the 8 logical cores) so I can save a lot of time.

Being an economist-statistician and not a developer, I'm completely uncertain on this subject. I looked at some forums and articles and I found a code that worked on my previous computer which had only 2 cores (R detected the 4 logical cores), it divided the computing time by almost 2, from 2h to 1h. On my new computer, this piece of code doesn't change at all the computing time, with or without this piece of code it runs arround 50 minutes (better processor, more ram memory).

Below are the two lines of code I added just above the code I put above. With of course the packages at the beginning of the code that I can give you

```
no_cores <- availableCores() - 1
plan(multicore, workers = no_cores)
```

Do you have any idea why it seemed to work on my previous computer and not on the new one when nothing has changed except the computer? Or a corrective action to take?

Comment: Why is this a `repeat` loop? To me it looks like the number of iterations is known. That would mean it should be a `for` loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: The foreach package gives you quite painless access to parallellization in a for-like loop.

Comment: @Roland II used a repeat loop because the n refers to a line number of the imported .csv file at the beginning of the code. Basically, it takes the text of a line number (n) and a column each time (up to 6, in red in the code).
The loop is just used to not write the code 137 times, to summarize. There are surely other ways to do it, of course.

I forgot to specify : each loop is independent. It calculates and then exports a .csv file at each end and then recalculates in the next loop (n+1) without taking into account the previous results.

Comment: OK, then this should be a `for` loop. I suggest you follow the advice above and use the `doParallel` package.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Please communicate in English.

Comment: I would not start by parrelizing the code. I would start by vectorizing the code. Also, you are assigning a lot of variables inside a loop with constants. Each assignment takes time. Move your constant assignments outside of your loop.

Comment: @AdamSampson The performance bottleneck is most likely the calcul_depense function or writing to file. It's unclear if the function can be parallelized.

Comment: Aggreed. We would need a different question on how to vectorize resultat=calcul_depense(annee,annee_profil,mois_de_debut,mois_de_fin,operateur,
                          profil_choisi,couplage,subvention,type,graine,seuil).

Comment: @Roland Obviously this a french man, I'm french too, why should I write to him in English ? Any way, if you want it, here is what I was suggesting : use fwrite from data.table instead of write.csv2, optimise the function calcul_depense (and for your sake, rename it expenses_calculations)

Comment: You should write in English so that everyone (including moderators) can understand. Comments are not for private conversations, use chat for that.